# How to find PID and taskkill it in one single line in command prompt

Tags: wmic, taskkill

I want to close a program using command line. to do so I will use this line of code to find the PID of the service,

```
wmic process get ProcessID,ExecutablePath | findstr /c:"D:\Eightcap - MT5\terminal64.exe"
```

and the result is something like this,

```
D:\Eightcap - MT5\terminal64.exe
20132
```

Now I want to close this PID using taskkill, how can I use both process in one single line in command prompt?

So far what I could do is using this code,

```
for /F %a in ('wmic process where ExecutablePath='D:\Eightcap - MT5\terminal64.exe' get ProcessId') do taskkill /pid %a
```

but it return `invalid alias verb.`. or if I use this,

```
for /F %a in ('wmic process where "ExecutablePath='D:\Eightcap - MT5\terminal64.exe'" get ProcessId') do taskkill /pid %a
```

it returns `Description = Invalid query`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it using this code,

```
for /F %a in ('wmic process where "ExecutablePath='D:\\Eightcap - MT5\\terminal64.exe'" get ProcessID') do taskkill /pid %a
```

Answer (score 0):

**The following worked for me -**

```
ps -aef | grep <Process name whose PID you want to know>
```

If you want to know the process of localhost then run the below command.

```
ps -aef | grep localhost
```

Comment: this is the message that I received with your code
`'ps' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: And what I want to do is taskkill program using PID and not image name